# Interactive Vizualizer of different Simplex -methods?

Tags: reference-request, linear-programming

My book [1] around the pages 80-100 outlines the theories behind different simplex methods such as Naive-Simplex, Revised-SImplex, Full-tableau-Simplex, Dual Simplex, etc-simplex --. It is very dry stuff and I would like to have some sort of interactive vizualisation of them. I tend to mix different methods together. Does some sort of graphical vizualiser exist about them?

[1] Introduction to linear Optimization, Dimitris Bertsimas, John N. Tsitsiklis, 1997

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to a [Geogebra Worksheet](http://www.geogebratube.org/material/show/id/489) that uses linear programming. You may be able to build your own worksheets in Geogebra to better suit your needs.